# HTML element position with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-position

If i have the following HTML snippet

```
...
<fieldset>
  <div>above or below</div>
  <div>content</div>
</fieldset>
...
```

How can I create CSS such that the `<div>above or below</div>` could be positioned above or below `<div>content</div>` without having to add repetitive markup and without affecting the document flow?

I have tried using `position: relative;` on the `fieldset` and then `position: absolute;` on the field div but the element then sits over any elements below it.

Comment: Are you referring to above and below as depth, i.e: `z-index` or are you talking about a vertical position?

Comment: vertical position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option you have would be to use `display: flex` and `flex-direction` in order to visually reverse the order of the two elements:

```css
fieldset {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

.below {
flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <div>above or below</div>
  <div>content</div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="below">
  <div>above or below</div>
  <div>content</div>
</fieldset>
```

You can also use `display: flex` and `order` if you need to add more elements into `fieldset`:

```css
fieldset {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.first {
  order: 1;
}

div {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <div>above or below</div>
  <div>content</div>
  <div>other stuff</div>
  <div>other stuff</div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <div>above or below</div>
  <div class="first">content</div>
  <div>other stuff</div>
  <div>other stuff</div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: For some reason I could not get it to work with `fieldset` when I switched to a `div` it worked fine